# Initializing AngularJS application with data

Tags: angularjs, routes, initialization

My AngularJS application has an URL structure like this: `/#/app/:appId/tickets` and `` `/#/app/:appId/users ``. That is, the logged-in user has multiple applications and the current application has an `:appId` that is always in the route.

Here's the question: when the user first logs in, I need to send them to a default route. I am currently hard-coding the default route like this:

```
.config( function myAppConfig ( urlRouterProvider ) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/1/tickets');
```

I am going to start using UUIDs in the backend for `:appId`, and I don't like hard-coding a value like this in code. So I need to set the default route when the app loads based on data retrieved from the server.

Unfortunately, I can't use the `$http` service inside config. What is the right way to set the default route based on data retrieved from the server when the app first initializes?

Comment: Are you using controller for handling the login functionality?

Comment: @BKM, I am not. I have a server-side page that handles login. I am considering adding a Node controller for login ...

Comment: Then you should write a service which checks for login and call that service method on your ".run" block.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the service in your MainController and save the value in a factory so that you can use wherever required.